# How to remove firewall block restriction on Azure web application URL?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Some of my apps are not working from some customers site, I later discovered that this was because I am using the default websites for my app hosting that is the url is myapp.azurewebsites.net which was not whitelisted on the customers firewall. The customer whitelisted my website domain name and its sub domain names .i.e mywebsite.com and *.mywebsite.com are all whitelisted.

If i were to create CNAME record which has a CNAME pointer to the azure default web app for example myapp.mywebsite.com points to myapp.azurewebsites.net, will this get around the issue ? Or do I need to whitelist myapp.azurewebsites.net Or its IP address that is the IP address of myapp.azurewebsites.net ?

Comment: “*If i were to create CNAME record which has a CNAME pointer to the azure default web app for example myapp.mywebsite.com points to myapp.azurewebsites.net, will this get around the issue ?*” This is, quite literally, impossible to answer affirmatively without a complete understanding of your customer’s firewall appliances and how they’re configured. Capabilities of firewalls vary *immensely*. This is also off-topic here on Stack Overflow and would be better suited on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) once you’re able to provide the requisite level of detail. See [ask]

Comment: I think my question has been misunderstood here, does the CNAMe matter or it it the Azure website IP address that needs whitelisting, please disregard firewall here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, by default, apps hosted in App Service are accessible directly through the internet and can reach only internet-hosted endpoints. So, typically, anyone with the URL without any specific local network/firewall/proxy restrictions can access the WebApp URL.

As I understand, your WebApp is open to the public and only a few users (on a specific network), have trouble accessing the site. Plus, there are no access restrictions that you have implemented from the WebApp side.

Just to highlight,

> Network administrators often deploy proxy servers, firewalls, or other
> devices, which can help secure and give control over how users access
> the internet. Rules designed to protect users can sometimes block or
> slow down legitimate business-related internet traffic. This traffic
> includes communications between you and Azure over the URLs listed
> here.
> Reference : [Allow the Azure portal URLs on your firewall or proxy server](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-safelist-urls?tabs=public-cloud)

So, on case-case basis, for the affected network, you may have them add `appservice.azure.com` (Azure App Services) in the allowed list.

Or

As your customer performed – “The customer whitelisted my website domain name and its sub domain names .i.e mywebsite.com and *.mywebsite.com are all whitelisted.” have them add the URLs to allowedlist.

Or

Since IP address of your WebApp (see the [reasons for the change](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips)), the best route would be for you to **set up a custom domain for your WebApp**.

Kindly check this doc - [Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=a%2Cazurecli)

The CNAME maps to the app's default hostname instead, which is less susceptible to change. | | Wildcard | *.contoso.com | CNAME record. |

-- As a side note (as indicated above), by setting up access restrictions, you can define a priority-ordered allow/deny list that controls network access to your app. Which is the opposite of your scenario, just sharing as FYI, in case you wish to know about access restrictions from WebApp side. [Set up Azure App Service access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a custom domain for my app, however for the staging/pre-production element of the app, is it possible to have this as a subdomain ? staging.mywebsite.com this way, should my customer choose to whitelist *.mywebsite.com, staging.mywebsite.com will also be whitelisted ? @AjayKumar-MSFT

Comment: Deployment slots are live apps with their own host names. Custom domain names are not swapped across slots. he slot's URL will be of the format http://sitename-slotname.azurewebsites.net. So, typically you should add both custom domains. See this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped  for additional info.